# Как получить всех номеров из последовательности Фибоначчи

Tags: c#

Нужно создать функцию с параметрами int startIndex, int endIndex. Он должен вернуть все числа из последовательности Фибоначчи. На пример, последовательност Фибоначчи: 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233, 377, 610, 987, 1597, 2584, 4181, 6765, 10946, 17711

Если я задам функцию параметры 5, 10 он должен вернуть List: 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34

Покопался в формулах но не нашел решение.

Comment: В чем именно проблема? Покажите код.

Comment: Непонятно,  в каких формулах тут копаться. Формула доя чисел Фибоначчи одна и всем известна. Больше тут никаких формул не требуется.

Answer (score 2):

Непонятно, в чём проблема. В общих чертах:

- создаёте пустой список
- вычисляете по очереди числа Фибоначчи, одновременно считаете какое это число по счёту
- если номер числа Фибоначчи лежит в заданных вам границах - добавляете его в список
- если достигнут `endIndex` - возвращаете накопленный список

На продвинутом уровне можно написать более красиво:

- сделать генератор чисел Фибоначчи с `yield return` очередного числа
- взять из этого генератора нужный кусок выдачи через `Linq` и превратить его в список